# document.title funcion can't set it work with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this line of code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.title = "<?php include('pot1.php');?>"
</script>
```

My pot1.php gives me an echo with one random number, but that code does not seem to work and I don't know why the echo doesn't appear in my title. Is anything wrong with the code?

pot1.php code:

```
<?php
@include_once('link1.php');
$cg = fetchinfo("value","info","name","current_game");
$cb = fetchinfo("cost","games","id",$cg);
$cb=round($cb,2);
echo '$'.$cb;
?>
```

This echo is working and is giving me values because I can see them in one div.

Comment: Show us contents of `pot1.php`.

Comment: pot1.php could be anything.  Hopefully it returns something.  Why wouldn't you run the include outside, set a variable, and echo THAT?

Comment: @lolbas post updated

Comment: show the code for `fetchinfo()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just do it like this:

```
<?php include('pot1.php');?>
```

Now we know that there is a variable set.  Echo that into the title tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.title = "<? echo $cb ?>"
</script>
```

The way you're doing it now...  I don't think you can include an entire PHP page and expect to behave like a simple string, even if that's all it returns.

Comment: `<? ?>` are PHP short tags, but they are likely not enabled on your server. It'd be better to do `<?= $cb ?>` (which are PHP short tags, but available regardless of setting in PHP 5.4+) or `<?php echo $cb; ?>` (available in all versions of PHP) instead.

Comment: Then you're not running it on a server that is executing the PHP.

Comment: @Chris Yes it was because i need to put <?php  thanks

Comment: @durbnpoisn you code was corred i didn't had the shot tags enabled, i have enabled it now and it works thanks

Comment: Spiffy! Glad to help.

Comment: @durbnpoisn Sorry for bother you again, i have another question about the same script because is not getting updated, i can do it here or i need to create another question? im new here i don't know if i can ask here :s

Comment: You're better off with a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Put the value you want inside a variable in the pot1.php file and use it on the title

```
<?php include('pot1.php');?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.title = "<?php echo $yourVar;?>"
</script>
```